# How to solve differential equation $dy/dx = y^2/(1+y^2)$ by inegration

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My first question is, how does one solve the following differential equation:

$$y' = y^2/(1+y^2)$$

My second question is, would it be possible to solve this using ordinary integration method, without relying on differential equation methods?

Comment: This ODE is of separable kind. Use the classical method to solve it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29

Comment: This is a classic seperation of variables problem. Lots of good responses already,so no point in me adding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is separable, hence 
$$\frac{1+y^2}{y^2}dy=dx\\ (1+\frac{1}{y^2})dy=dx$$
Integrate both sides, you get 
$$y-\frac{1}{y} =x+ c$$

Comment: Minor error leaving out the dy "form" term. Fixed it. You're welcome. : )

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, in a fashion - simply flip the derivative using the chain rule
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{1+y^2}{y^2} = \frac{1}{y^2} +1,
$$
integrating we have $x$ as a function of $y$.
$$
x(y) = -\frac{1}{y} + y + c. 
$$